# Error detection for chatGPT API requests in swift

Tags: swift, swift5, openai-api

I am learning about how to make a chat app using chat gpt in swift. I am following along on the iOS academy chat gpt tutorial, steps taken:

1. added in wrapper package from - https://github.com/adamrushy/OpenAISwift
2. generated api key on chat gpt.
3. added code below with the real api key.

problem: The chat does not generate a response. the code seems fine, but no response or error is returned. ive waited and hour to see if the api key needed time before it worked, but still have the same result with no gpt response unfortunately. Any ideas?

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData
import OpenAISwift


final class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
    init() {}
    
    private var client: OpenAISwift?
    
    func setup(){
        client = OpenAISwift(authToken: "MY-REAL-API-KEY")
    }
    
    func send(text: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        client?.sendCompletion(with: text, maxTokens: 500, completionHandler: { result in
            switch result {
            case.success(let model):
                let output = model.choices?.first?.text ?? ""
                completion(output)
            case.failure(let error):
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
    
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State var text = ""
    @State var models = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            ForEach(models, id: \.self) { string in
                Text(string)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            HStack{
                TextField("type here", text: $text)
                Button("send"){
                    send()
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.setup()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    func send() {
        guard !text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        
        models.append("Me: \(text)")
        viewModel.send(text: text) { response in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.models.append("GPT: " + response)
                print(text)
                print(response)
                
                self.text = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works well for me (with my key). The free subscription is free until they ask for money,
 that is, after you use $5 or the time limit is reached. So my suspicion
 is that your subscription has run out. In that case,
 there will be no response from the server until you pay them. Login into your account, find your profile and check your account state.

 Note you should use `@StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()`

Comment: The package is known for not handling response errors. It also doesn’t follow OpenAIs best practice for APIKeys.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine oh yes very good, it must be setting up the api account so. i was able to generate an api key but didn't have to put any billing information into the account at all, so it must be that...i guess. thanks for testing the code, good to know it works okay so its just my admin side of things that's wrong.

Comment: @loremipsum yes that's is true, if i intend to release this app properly i would need to protect the API key is that correct? i am new to this so still trying to investigate best practices, how would you set it up so the key is protected?

Comment: I use Firebase Functions + Secret Manager. I keep my APIKey and Organization in the secret manager.

Comment: Yes, the code you have works. You will have to pay money to keep going.
 I (and many others) run into this problem as well.
 I tried to use another email, and another key, and that does not work.
 You have to use a different phone number or pay money.
 I use `Keychain` to store my apikey, this is what Apple recommends.
 The `OpenAISwift` is not perfect (eg errors) and is slow to accept updates, but
 it's so easy to use.

Comment: OpenAISwift does not follow best practices because it stores and transmits the key from the client side. It doesn’t matter where you put it in the client when it is transmitted it is compromised.

Comment: https://approov.io/blog/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack

Comment: From OpenAI docs: `Remember that your API key is a secret! Do not share it with others or expose it in any client-side code (browsers, apps).`, then they ask you to login and type your password through your browser, ...

Comment: I found a ChatGPT SDK for IOS. It is well-documented, easy to setup up, less complex, and seamlessly integrates with the IOS environment. You can try it out here : https://github.com/DevCrew-io/chatgpt-ios-sdk